# Pycharm(python3.6): module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm with python3.6, but it sends me this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

And when I try to install package numpy(or any other) I get

```
 AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader
```

My pip is

> pip3 -V
>
> pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

Although, it works perfectly well with python 3.4 - I suppose it could be related with the fact that have multiple versions installed, and when compiling, PyCharm goes to python3 and not to python3.6 :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
import numpy as np
```

[usr/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCDtB.png)  __
[usr/local/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNvUU.png) __

So, do you have any idea how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Simply add that version `3.6` to pycharm and it should be ok.

Comment: Addition: use that version of python inn the pycharm project and it should be fine.

Comment: @George Oops.. Sorry! I forgot to thank you! :) Everything works perfectly since then